# Does FacebookSDK always show LaunchScreen after Share or Login and before get back to the current screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

I am developing an app with `Facebook` share and login. When I do Login or I share something in `Facebook`, the `LaunchScreen` of my app is displayed before show the current `view`. It is just a second, but I would like to know if there is any way to avoid that step.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's not  facebook sdk which causing your app to display launchscreen its iOS**

and ans is NO.
As apple wrote in [HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html) 
`Every app must supply a launch file or at least one static image.`

so you can not avoid to using that and second thing is that apple showing it
because your application will take time to back active and mean while apple showing 
launchscreen, so that application look more responsive